# How to add QueryTextListener for searchView in android fragment?

Tags: android, mobile, menu, toolbar, searchview

I have an in app contacts list screen (which is a fragment) and I want to add a searchView in my toolbar. This is my code:

Fragment code:

```
    private lateinit var contactsToolbar: Toolbar

      override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        contactsToolbar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_toolbar)
        contactsToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.contacts_menu)
        contactsToolbar.title = "Contacts"
.......
      return rootView
    }

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
inflater.inflate(R.menu.contacts_menu, menu)
val search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "new query $query")
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "new text $newText")
        return true
    }
})
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
```

}

and this is my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

I can see that the searchView is displayed in the fragmanet as expected but the queryTextListener never gets called. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! Not sure if is the most elegant one but might help somebody in the future. Here is the fix:

1. In the `onCreateView` add this line of code:

yourActivity().setSupportActionBar(contactsToolbar)

2. This will make the searchView listener work but it might display the menu from the activity if you have one. To prevent this from happening and this line in `onCreateOptionsMenu` before inflating your menu.

   menu.clear()

Answer (score 0):

May be you can init the SearchView after onCreateOptionsMenu method?

I cannot sure it is true, but I met the same question as you, the text listener doesn't work.

because I init my SearchView  like

val mySearchView by lazy{
...
}